# search box duplication in auto suggesting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image]

I create a search box that auto suggest through database records, whenever I search or type something my search box is duplicating. How to remove duplication of my search box?

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search_list").keyup(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data:"keyword="+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){

                $("#suggestion").show();
                $("#suggestion").html(data);
                $("#search_list").css("background","#FFF");
            }
            });
        });
    });
    //To select name
    function selectName(val) {
    $("#search_list").val(val);
    $("#suggestion").hide();
    }
    </script>
```

--------------php--------------

```
    <?php
    foreach($result as $name) {
    ?>
    <div class="list">
     <a href="#" class="style_suggestions" onClick="selectName('<?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php } } ?>
```

-------------HTML------------------

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Nava</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible content=" ie="edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="frmSearch">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_list" name="search_nv_box" placeholder="Name"/>
      <div id="suggestion"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: provide your html

Comment: can you try following answer. empty() your existing dataset first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First you need to clear or empty you existing suggestions and load new data after that.

```
$("#suggestion").empty();
$("#suggestion").html(data);
```

So it should be ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search_list").keyup(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data:"keyword="+$(this).val(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#suggestion").empty();
                $("#suggestion").html(data);
                $("#suggestion").show();
                $("#search_list").css("background","#FFF");
            }
            });
        });
    });
```

Also you should only return single div element from php. It seems currently for each record it creates a div.

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $name) {
?>
    <div class="list">
     <a href="#" class="style_suggestions" onClick="selectName('<?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?></a>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

It should be,

```
<div class="list">
  <?php
    foreach($result as $name) {
  ?>
   <a href="#" class="style_suggestions" onClick="selectName('<?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?>');"><?php echo $name["n_Name"]; ?></a>

  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: the code does not work, it has a same result still duplicate my search box

Comment: @dionell attache screenshot what you mean by duplicate.

Comment: once i search something into my input, another input will show.

Comment: try this  $("#search_list").css("background","").css("background","#FFF");

Comment: not sure but does it allow you to input in that duplicate field?

Comment: yes it allows, but the data from the database is not show. its just like a input type with no function.so i can still search using the first input and the second input is not.

Comment: $('#suggestion').html(data);  when i use this syntax my website UI are show in the suggestion box

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;

try this query for fetch records

Comment: not work, $('#suggestion').html(data);  when i use this syntax my website UI are show in the suggestion box

Comment: cant you send query how to get data from database ?

Comment: thank you for helping me I appreciate it, but its not about the query. my script should be like this and it works. 

$('#suggestion').html($(data).find('#sug_list'));